# Using a JList in a JApplet (Small Issue)

Tags: java, swing, switch-statement, jlist, japplet

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;
import java.util.*;
public class Number extends JApplet implements ListSelectionListener
{
    public static JList list;
    public void init() 
    {
        ArrayList<String> arr = new ArrayList<String>(); //making an arraylist with all the colors
        arr.add("Red");
        arr.add("Green");
        arr.add("Blue");
        arr.add("Yellow");
        arr.add("Orange");
        arr.add("Purple");
        arr.add("Random");
        arr.add("White");

        list = new JList(arr.toArray()); //making the array list

        add(list); //I think this may be the source of m
        this.setVisible(true);
        list.addListSelectionListener(this);
        String x = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter a number from 0-9: ");
        int cool = Integer.parseInt(x);
    }
    public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) //trying to change the background of the applet using a JList, and this is where im running into the biggest problem
    {
        Container c = getContentPane();
        int y = list.getSelectedIndex();
        switch(y)
        {
            case 0:
            c.setBackground(Color.red);
            case 1:
            c.setBackground(Color.green);
            case 2:
            c.setBackground(Color.blue);
            case 3:
            c.setBackground(Color.yellow);
            case 4:
            c.setBackground(Color.orange);
            case 5:
            c.setBackground(Color.magenta);
            case 6:
            c.setBackground(new Color((int)(Math.random()*255), (int)(Math.random()*255), (int)(Math.random()*255)));
            case 7:
            c.setBackground(Color.white);
        }
    }
    public void paint(Graphics g)
    {
        super.paint(g);
        String x = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter a number from 0-9: ");
        int cool = Integer.parseInt(x);
        switch(cool)
        {
            //Switch structure that draws numbers
        }
        }
    }
```

Im running into an issue with the JList not showing up in the JApplet. I think that the JList might be being added to a frame that is non-existent but im not entirely sure. And yes I realize I have a huge amount of imports that are unnessasary. Just wondering if I could get some help with this small problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
switch(y)
{
    case 0:
    c.setBackground(Color.red);
    case 1:
```

Should be:

```
switch(y)
{
    case 0:
    c.setBackground(Color.red);
    break; //VERY important if we don't want it to 'fall through' to next statements
    case 1:
```